# How to remove strings before nth character in a text?

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamically generated  text like this

```
xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-Map-B-844-0
```

How can I remove everything before `Map ...`? I know there is a hard coded way to do this by using `substring()` but as I said these strings are dynamic and before `Map ..` can change so I need to do this dynamically  by removing everything before  `4th` index of `-` character.

Comment: Are you trying to remove everything before the last occurrence of `Map`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could remove all four minuses and the characters between from start of the string.

```js
var string = 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-Map-B-844-0',
    stripped = string.replace(/^([^-]*-){4}/, '');
    
console.log(stripped);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just find the index of `Map` and use it to slice the string:

```js
let str = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-Map-B-844-0"
let ind = str.indexOf("Map")
console.log(str.slice(ind))
```

If you prefer a regex (or you may have occurrences of `Map` in the prefix) you man match exactly what you want with:

```js
let str = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-Map-B-844-0"
let arr = str.match(/^(?:.+?-){4}(.*)/)
console.log(arr[1])
```

Comment: What if `xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx` contains `Map` keyword??

Comment: That's a fair point if that's a possibility. @Sphinx. I read `remove everything before Map ...` to indicate that it's not a possibility.

Comment: @planet_hunter then use `lastIndexOf`. But we don't know from the OP's description which one is desired

Comment: You're probably right @Sphinx I added a regex alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I would just split on the word Map and take the  first index

`var splitUp = 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-Map-B-844-0'.split('Map')
var firstPart = splitUp[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Uses `String.replace` with regex expression should be the popular solution.

Based on the OP states: `so I need to do this dynamically by removing everything before 4th index of - character.`,

I think another solution is `split('-')` first, then join the strings after 4th `-`.

```js
let test = 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-Map-B-844-0'
console.log(test.split('-').slice(4).join('-'))
```